# HttpServletResponse redirect doesn't work, but redirecting from the jsp page does

Tags: jsp

I have a Spring project which has two APIs.  The first API will redirect to a JSP page in my WEB-INF folder.  This JSP will then post to my second API with some data.  From my second API, I am trying to redirect to another site based on the data I collected.  Originally, I had my controller with the following code:

```
String redirectURL = "https://www.my.app.com";
Cookie cookie = new Cookie("token", map.get("token_value"));
cookie.setPath("/");
cookie.setDomain(".my.app.com");
cookie.setHttpOnly(true);
servletResponse.addCookie(cookie);
servletResponse.sendRedirect(redirectURL);
```

However, it would fail with a CORS failure when I tried to redirect to the URL based on 'Redirect has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header' (I don't own the landing site, and I am testing using localhost:8080).  So I then added a header for the response with `servletResponse.addHeader("Location", redirectURL)` and in my JSP callback function from my post, I am using

```
success: function(data, status, xhr) {
            window.location.replace(xhr.getResponseHeader("Location"));
        }
```

Which correctly redirects to the URL, but I lose my cookie.  I would rather not have the redirect happen on my jsp page, what am I doing wrong?  I also tried inserting a second AJAX call in the success callback to get the URL with the cookie, with the same issue.  So the GET call is getting blocked by the 'No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource' issue.  Is there a way around this?  If I make a redirect to the "my.app.com" url before redirecting to the JSP, it works.  It's only after I land on the JSP that I can't make the get call.